# GIT - Can you keep files that you don't want to track but not ignore

Tags: git, svn

I have an SVN repo, on which apart from the standard Trunk and Branches folder, there are also other folders like Documents, POCs, Archives etc. at the same level of Trunk.

These are basically "non-code" files/folders that we don't want to be versioned (they are not part of trunk or any branch).

We are shifting from SVN to GIT. Is there any convention in GIT to keep such files in the repository without tracking them (not using ignore)?

I am using the command `git svn clone --trunk=/Trunk --branches=/Branches   http://blah.com/svn/repo repo` to clone the svn repository into a git repository.

Comment: "in the repository" and "not tracking" are incompatible statements. Something is either in the repository and tracked, or not in the repository (and should be ignored so they don't accidentally get added to the repository).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any convention in GIT to keep such files in the repository without tracking them (not using ignore)?

No.

Fundamentally, Git "likes to" make the work-tree match the commit, whenever you check out a commit.  That is, suppose you have commits `badf00d`, `cafedad`, and `ac0ffee` in your repository (perhaps the first one is the tip of branch `master` and the second is the tip of branch `develop`, and you just check out the third one by hash ID, to view it for a moment).  When you tell Git to check out `ac0ffee`, Git looks at your *current* commit—let's say that's `badf00d`—and your *new goal* commit of `ac0ffee` and says: hm, according to my records, `badf00d` has file `snort` but `ac0ffee` doesn't, so I'll just *remove* `snort` now.  Then if you go back from `ac0ffee` to `badf00d` or to `cafedad`, both of which have versions of file `snort`, it will put it back.

What this means is that if you choose to commit your `Documents/` files in a "side branch" that is not used from the main branch, and then *check out* the side branch, the `Documents/` files will all show up.  (Great!)  But then as soon as you switch *back* to the main (master or development) branch, Git will *remove* all the `Documents/` files.  The files are in the *repository*, so Git knows to add and remove them from the *work-tree* when you go to commits that have them or lack them.

#### Git's index, and what "tracked" files are

Git's *index* is perhaps best described as *where you build the next commit you will make*.  As you work in Git, you modify files in your work-tree, the same as in any version control system.  But before you make your *next* commit, you must `git add` the work-tree versions to copy them from the work-tree into the index.  Until then, what's in the index is the *current* commit—and in fact just running `git diff` shows you the difference between the index as it stands right now, and the work-tree.  Once you `git add` all the current versions of all files, so that the index matches the work-tree, `git diff` will show *nothing* (but `git diff --cached` or `git diff --staged` will show all your changes: this command compares the current commit to the index, instead of comparing the index to the work-tree).

A file is tracked, in Git, *if and only if* it is in the index.  In other words, file *F* is tracked only if it will be in the *next* commit you make.  You change a file from tracked to untracked by *removing* it from the index.  You change a file from untracked (present in the working directory, but not in the index) by `git add`-ing it.

#### Your best bet may be to have the "side files" as untracked and never committed to *this* repository

All of the above means that if you have a `Documents/` directory in the work-tree but not in the index, it will be sitting around as "untracked".  Git will complain at you that it *is* untracked, so you would probably want to add `Documents/` to your `.gitignore` to suppress the complaints.  This won't make the files untracked!  It will just shut up the complaints, and also prevent `git add` from accidentally *adding* the files *to* the index.

But how will you get these `Documents/` files into your work-tree in the first place?

There are plenty of possibilities.  But if you don't want them to become tracked (and hence included in each commit), you must make sure they don't get into your index.  The `.gitignore` file will help here, but if you get the files into the index in *any* way, they will become tracked.  Suppose, then, that you have them in the repository, in a special side branch (perhaps called `documentation`) that is entirely unrelated to the current branch.  If you `git checkout` that branch, the files will appear in your work-tree, but they will now be in your index.  Moreover, all your *other* tracked work-tree files that are *not* in that special side branch will disappear!  And as soon as you `git checkout` the main branch to work on things, all the `Documentation/` files will disappear from both index (good) and work-tree (bad) and you will no longer have your documentation visible.  So that's kind of awkward.

You could use the new `git worktree` feature to keep a *separate* work-tree, in a separate directory, that checks out the `documentation` branch.  Then instead of `./Documentation`, you will have `../alt-work-tree/Documentation`.  Now your Documentation and source can co-exist in the same repository, but in independent branches.

Or, you can put all your `Documentation` files into a *different repository*.  You can then clone the main repository, with the normal source, to the main directory, and the `Documentation` repository, to `./Documentation` within the main repository.  Since the `Documentation` sub-tree is its own, separate, repository, nothing you do there will affect the main repository, nor vice versa.

If you want, you can even make these sub-repositories into "submodules".  I dislike submodules and would try to avoid this myself, but they could be useful for this particular purpose.

Note that if the documents really are not versioned *at all* (which seems unlikely and wrong), you don't need a version control system for them.  If they are versioned by the documentation system (which seems likely), perhaps you can just let it do the versioning, and not keep them in Git at all.  This is the same, from a high level perspective, as keeping them in a separate Git repository—the only real difference being that you *cannot* mark them as a submodule, since Git's submodules are Git repositories.

Comment: Thank you. I like the option of keeping a separate repository for documentation. Although, I don't know what `submodules` are. Will explore that option as well.